# I can't understand why it doesn't display the float in the file (binary file)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct etudiant{
  char nom[10];
  float moy;
};

void AjoutEtudiant(struct etudiant E,FILE *ficheierEtudiant) {
  ficheierEtudiant = fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","w");
  char rep;

  do{
    printf("Saisir nom etudiant a Ajouter: ");
    scanf("%s",&E.nom);
    printf("Saisir son Moyen: ");
    scanf("%f",&E.moy);
    fwrite (&E, sizeof(struct etudiant), 1,ficheierEtudiant);
    if(fwrite!=0){
        printf("\n\nEtudaint Ajouter avec succees !\n\n");
    }
    printf("\nvoulez vouz Ajouter un autre etudiant? (O,N): ");
    scanf("%s",&rep);
  } while(toupper(rep)!='N');

  fclose(ficheierEtudiant);
}

void EcrireListeEtudiant(struct etudiant E, FILE* fichierEtudiant) {
 fichierEtudiant=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","rb");
  while(fread(&E,sizeof(struct etudiant),1,fichierEtudiant))
    printf("Nom Etudiant: %s",E.nom,"| Moyen= %f \n",E.moy);

  fclose(fichierEtudiant);
}

int main()
{
   FILE *fichierEtudiant;
   struct etudiant E;

   AjoutEtudiant(E,fichierEtudiant);
   EcrireListeEtudiant(E,fichierEtudiant);
}
```

I add names and their marks (float) in the file but when I try to display them it only shows the name and ignore the float parts in the file!  I have tried many ways but ended up messing it up.  Can someone help me to understand the issue?

Comment: thanks mate .but about displaying the float it doesn't display them it only displays the names

Comment: @xing The strange printf has two format strings, each followed by a argument - and is far from a correct use of printf. Probably helpful: `printf("Nom Etudiant: %s| Moyen= %f \n", E.nom, E.moy);`

Comment: The const pointer-to-function null test `if(fwrite!=0)` is always true; one probably intended to set a variable to the value that `fwrite` returns, and then test that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the name and the moyen, change

```
printf("Nom Etudiant: %s",E.nom,"| Moyen= %f \n",E.moy);
```

to

```
printf("Nom Etudiant: %s| Moyen= %f \n", E.nom, E.moy);
```

This is necessary, because printf always takes a single format string and then all the arguments. If the first string only describes a single argument, the others will be ignored.
In your code, the second argument is the second half of the format string and the third argument is the moyen you are missing in the output. Both are ignored.

With the single, longer format string as proposed, two arguments are described, so both are found and used and both end up in the output.